# How to connect to Google Cloud SQL Proxy from Django?

Tags: sql, django, google-app-engine, proxy

I have happily managed to run Google SQL Proxy on port 5432.
I was trying to follow the tutorial https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment
but I do not know how to setup the settings.py file.
There is a mixture of terms which is very confusing for me:

- Google App Engine default authentication login / password from gcloud
- Google App Engine service authentication login / password from gcloud
- Project instance name
- Database password
- Database instance name
- Database connection name
- Database login / password

I would be happy if there was anybody who could make a clear picture what do they mean and how to make this example working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick summary of the terminology you are having issues with:

- Google App Engine default authentication login / password from gcloud: The credentials related to the project owner (the account you used to create the project).
- Google App Engine service authentication login / password from gcloud: This means that you would use a service account to access gcloud.

For the authentication process, it is better to generate a credentials file and use it to identify your account. It is recommended to generate the credentials as a JSON file (no password needed), and then import it to gcloud. After that, just export an environment variable indicating where to find the credentials file:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=”[PATH_TO_JSON_FILE]”
```

As for the terms related to Cloud SQL, this is what they mean:

- Project instance name: You must mean the project name, which is the name of the Google Cloud project you created to work on this tutorial.
- Database instance name: The name you gave to the Cloud SQL instance (e.g. polls-instance).
- Database login/password: The username and password you created for accessing the database.
- Database password: The database has no password itself, so this would indicate the password for the user you created.
- Database connection name: The name you use to connect to the database through the Cloud SQL Proxy.

To get the database connection name, use the following command, changing [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME] with the name you used for the instance:

```
gcloud sql instances describe [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]
```

If you’re having trouble with the requirements.py installation, you can try preparing a virtual environment for python3 by using this command:

```
virtualenv -p python3 envname
```

If the problem persists, try installing each module individually with pip. Following these steps you should have no problem going through the tutorial.